# Searching exact match of a list of strings inside a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, loops

I have a list of lists:

```
result = [['GELATIN', '76.0 mg', '40 %', 'Gelatin to 100.000 g Table 7 Capsule Quantity per unit flavouring dose Quantity per unit dose Components Nominal mass of capsule 76.0 mg In the cap (40 %) 30.4 mg flavouring agent corresponds to 1 '], 
          ['GELATIN', '45.6 mg', '14.5 %', 'Gelatin including water of a certain percentage'], 
          ['INK', '76.0 mg', '40 %', 'ink is used as diluent far as this is necessary for the markets. Table 4 Atenolol granules Components mg/capsule Granules Active ingredients Atenolol 50.00]]
```

and a list of strings:

```
agent = ['Flavouring Agent', 'Anti-Tacking Agent', 'Preservative', 'Colouring Agent', 'Ph Adjusting Agent', 'Plasticizer', 'Diluent']
```

For each sub-list from `result`, I want to search for an element from the `agent` list to be anywhere in the sub-list. If such element exists, add it at the beginning of the sub-list as a new element.

Expected output:

```
new_result = [['Flavouring Agent', 'GELATIN', '76.0 mg', '40 %', 'Gelatin to 100.000 g Table 7 Capsule Quantity per unit flavouring dose Quantity per unit dose Components Nominal mass of capsule 76.0 mg In the cap (40 %) 30.4 mg flavouring agent corresponds to 1 '], 
              ['GELATIN', '45.6 mg', '14.5 %', 'Gelatin including water of a certain percentage'], 
              ['Diluent', 'INK', '76.0 mg', '40 %', 'ink is used as diluent far as this is necessary for the markets. Table 4 Atenolol granules Components mg/capsule Granules Active ingredients Atenolol 50.00]]
```

This is because `'Flavouring Agent'` is present in the last element of the first sub-list; And `'Diluent'` is present in the last element of the last sub-list.

Effort untill now:

```
newl=[]                
for jj in agent:        
    for e in result:
        for ll in e:

            if jj in ll:
                #print(jj,ll)
                newl.append([jj,ll])
                break
```

Comment: What did you try,where is your code, whats the problem?

Comment: Added for reference

Comment: And what output does that give you?

Comment: It's returning empty list

Comment: that might be because of cases... Your `agents` list has: `'Flavouring Agent'` while the `result` list has `'flavouring agent'`

Comment: thanks. worked when I did `if jj.lower() in ll.lower():`

Comment: But it's not retaining the original format of the list 'result'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem I believe is confusion with the neting levels, and also the order of the loops. Assuming you want to preserve the order of the original list (and not omit elements), your outer loop should be on the list. Then you want to check for any word from `agent` present in the list. We can use a "flag" variable to add only one "agent":

```py
res = []
for sub in result:
    new_sub = sub
    agent_found = False
    for ag in agent:
        if agent_found:
            break
        for item in sub:
            if ag.lower() in item.lower():
                new_sub = [ag] + new_sub
                agent_found = True
                break
    if not agent_found:
        new_sub = [" "] + new_sub
    res.append(new_sub)
```

Gives:

```
[['Flavouring Agent', 'GELATIN', '76.0 mg', '40 %', 'Gelatin to 100.000 g Table 7 Capsule Quantity per unit flavouring dose Quantity per unit dose Components Nominal mass of capsule 76.0 mg In the cap (40 %) 30.4 mg flavouring agent corresponds to 1 '], 
 ['GELATIN', '45.6 mg', '14.5 %', 'Gelatin including water of a certain percentage'], 
 ['Diluent', 'INK', '76.0 mg', '40 %', 'ink is used as diluent far as this is necessary for the markets. Table 4 Atenolol granules Components mg/capsule Granules Active ingredients Atenolol 50.00']]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How can I optimise this code so that I add only the first match from the 'agent' list? Right now if I am getting more than one match, it's getting appended.

Comment: It's returning null now post the changes

Comment: for cases where there is no match, like "['GELATIN', '45.6 mg', '14.5 %', 'Gelatin including water of a certain percentage']," in the output, how can I append an empty string to the output. example: `[' ', 'GELATIN', '45.6 mg', '14.5 %', 'Gelatin including water of a certain percentage']`

Answer (score 0):

```py
new_result=[]

for l in result:
    temp_results=[]
    for ag in agent:
        if ag in l:
            temp_results.append(ag)
    new_result.append(temp_result)
```

Comment: This is returning empty lists. Can you please check

Comment: Can you explain how you expect "Flavouring Agent" in your new result's first list, when "Flavouring Agent isn't in the first list of the input list?

Comment: @user1558604 it is inside the string that is the last element. Your code searches if the agent is in the sub-list, but you need to search if it's in any element of the sub-list

Comment: Ok, the other answer provides the better solution then